# How does plot(allEffects(mod)) in r treat categorical variables not included in the graphed interaction?

Tags: r, plot, interaction, mixed-models

If I use the code:

```
plot(allEffects(AP18), multiline = TRUE, rescale.axis = FALSE, main = NULL)
```

for the following model:

```
AP18<-glmer(cbind(NPP,NPC)~Cond+OTTM+SlopeAp+EssCondEnd+SlopeAp*Cond+SlopeAp*OTTM+(1|Ind)+(1|Groupe),family=binomial, data=SElearn)
```

I get the following:
[image]

Cond has 3 levels (A, B and C). In the third plot, of the interaction between OTTM and SlopeAP, what is it doing with Cond? I ask because I am trying to recreate the graphs using predict. With a continuous variable that wasn't included in the model I would set it to 0, but with the categorical I don't know what to do. It is not set to the reference value (in this case A), because doing that does not give the same graph.

For reference, the model summary is:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: cbind(NPP, NPC) ~ Cond + OTTM + SlopeAp + EssCondEnd + SlopeAp *  
    Cond + SlopeAp * OTTM + (1 | Ind) + (1 | Groupe)
   Data: SElearn
Control: glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 2e+05))

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  1023.1   1063.8   -500.5   1001.1      287 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.4584 -0.9527  0.0458  0.8498  3.5794 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance  Std.Dev. 
 Ind    (Intercept) 3.338e-01 5.777e-01
 Groupe (Intercept) 1.997e-15 4.468e-08
Number of obs: 298, groups:  Ind, 20; Groupe, 4

Fixed effects:
                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)      -1.535316   0.618425  -2.483 0.013042 *  
CondB             0.937548   0.411961   2.276 0.022857 *  
CondC             2.415791   0.402306   6.005 1.92e-09 ***
OTTMCBA           3.610364   1.085016   3.327 0.000876 ***
SlopeAp          15.657892   7.896060   1.983 0.047367 *  
EssCondEnd        0.019554   0.006844   2.857 0.004275 ** 
CondB:SlopeAp    -6.188813   4.297260  -1.440 0.149817    
CondC:SlopeAp   -14.062097   4.117263  -3.415 0.000637 ***
OTTMCBA:SlopeAp -35.422102  11.157396  -3.175 0.001500 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Based on the help page, it looks like whatever function given in `typical` is used on the model matrix by default. So if your data are balanced among your factor levels you could make predictions for all three levels on the link scale and then average them and inverse link for plotting. Side note: often other covariates are fixed to their means/medians, not to 0.

Comment: It seems that sometimes taking the average response would make sense, others not at all. At least now I understand what it is doing - thanks for your help!